# How to use a Wikidata SPARQL Query and get the url to SVG image of chart

Tags: sparql, wikidata

If I run this SPARQL query

```
#defaultView:BubbleChart
#TEMPLATE={"template":"Overall causes of death ranking of ?thing ","variables":{"?thing": {"query":"SELECT ?id  (COUNT(?id) AS ?count) WHERE {  ?sub wdt:P509 ?y.  ?sub wdt:P31 ?id. } GROUP BY ?id "} } }
SELECT ?cid ?cause (COUNT(*) AS ?count) WHERE {
  BIND(wd:Q5 AS ?thing)
  ?pid wdt:P31 ?thing.
  ?pid wdt:P509 ?cid.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?cid rdfs:label ?cause.
    FILTER((LANG(?cause)) = "en")
  }
}
GROUP BY ?cid ?cause
ORDER BY DESC(?count) ?cause
LIMIT 50
```

in the [Wikidata Query Editor](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23added%20before%202016-10%0A%0A%23defaultView%3ABubbleChart%0A%23TEMPLATE%3D%7B%22template%22%3A%22Overall%20causes%20of%20death%20ranking%20of%20%3Fthing%20%22%2C%22variables%22%3A%7B%22%3Fthing%22%3A%20%7B%22query%22%3A%22SELECT%20%3Fid%20%20%28COUNT%28%3Fid%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%20WHERE%20%7B%20%20%3Fsub%20wdt%3AP509%20%3Fy.%20%20%3Fsub%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fid.%20%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fid%20%22%7D%20%7D%20%7D%0ASELECT%20%3Fcid%20%3Fcause%20%28COUNT%28%2A%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20BIND%28wd%3AQ5%20AS%20%3Fthing%29%0A%20%20%3Fpid%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fthing.%0A%20%20%3Fpid%20wdt%3AP509%20%3Fcid.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcid%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcause.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3Fcause%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcid%20%3Fcause%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fcount%29%20%3Fcause%0Alimit%2050), I have the option to download the bubblechart as an SVG file using the menu Download > SVG Image

[image: Resulting bubble chart of the SPARQL query]

I am looking for a way to generate or retrieve the URL to this SVG file when I execute the same SPARQL script programatically. In that case, only the raw data is returned (as JSON).

> {   "head" : {
>       "vars" : [ "cid", "cause", "count" ]   },   "results" : {
>       "bindings" : [ {
>         "cid" : {
>           "type" : "uri",
>           "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q12152"
>         },
>         "cause" : {
>           "xml:lang" : "en",
>           "type" : "literal",
>           "value" : "myocardial infarction"
>         },
>         "count" : {
>           "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer",
>           "type" : "literal",
>           "value" : "5837"
>         }
>       }, {
>         "cid" : {
>           "type" : "uri",
>           "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q12192"
>         },
>         "cause" : {
>           "xml:lang" : "en",
>           "type" : "literal",
>           "value" : "pneumonia"
>         },
>         "count" : {
>           "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer",
>           "type" : "literal",
>           "value" : "2177"
>         }.... etc

Comment: I don't think this is possible. See at `Link -> Short URL to result`. When you open this in a browser, you can check the source code - there is a lot of embedded Javascript code, thus, it looks like being generated dynamically. Sure, that should be some export function to SVG, but I'm not sure whether this can be handled in a single HTTP request. You should ask for details on the Wikidata mailing list.

Comment: Followup: All my research has led to the conclusion this is not possible. Feel free to prove me wrong, but maybe this can save others some time.

Comment: It is indeed generated dynamically, but you could request the feature on https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/ tagging #wikidata

Comment: I filed https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T209392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no URL to this SVG because it is generated by the Javascript running in the browser after retrieving JSON results. If you want to get it programmatically, I think using browser automation to run the Javascript code and obtain the file using simulated user actions would be the quickest way to achieve it.